# Why do dwellers think they can't carry 100 items?

Tags: fallout-shelter

At some point, a patch allowed dwellers in the wasteland to realize they have 100 items and automatically head back to the vault. It's not foolproof, however, and I regularly get dwellers coming back with about 60 items while claiming to be full (just now a dweller brought back 61).

All my wasteland explorers are lvl 50 with 10 in all specials. This 'bug' does not seem to relate to total strength (dwellers with 10 STR can bring back 100 items, while dwellers with 12 or 13 have been observed bringing back around 60). I have over 400 storage, so that's not it. I keep 18 dwellers in the waste at all times.

Does anyone know what's causing this? Is it a bug or working as intended? How can I mitigate it?

Comment: The process of counting the items are a huge PITA... how are you counting them to make sure you didn't skip any?

Comment: @Nelson subtraction when the dweller returns

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think this may be a bug but there might just be a random number generator somewhere between 60 and 100. So if you send a dewller out into the wasteland then when he or she will come back to the vault when they reach this randomly generated number. If you want to get legendary items then do quests because I heard that in the newest patch, you won't find legendary items in the wasteland. Anyway, completing a quest is always the best way to get rare and legendary items so I suggest upgrading your Overseer's Office to level 3.

Sending Dwellers out is a good option for common and rare items but you don't get as much junk as in quests.

P.S. Maybe you can go through that patch again.